# Vb.net How do i get a Dim statement between ""?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to get a Dim statement between "".

Dim TEST As String = "1" & "2" & "3"

SQL = "SELECT * from **MYDATABASE** where **"this is were i want the dim statement"** like '%" & search.Text & "%'"

I am tring to instert multiple tables inside it.
How will this work?

Comment: Please explain how your SQL variable should be initialized

Comment: SQL = "SELECT * from MYDATABASE where TEST like '%" & search.Text & "%'". TEST is 1, 2 and 3. Thats what i try to make. Would be great for a solution for this. Thank you

Comment: So you want to search for the field TEST where it contains the number 1 or the number 2 or the number 3?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnarability.  You need to use parameters.

Comment: The statement TEST are tables, not actually 1, 2 or 3. I am trying to make multiple tables inside it. Its only working with only one table like SQL = "SELECT * from MYDATABASE where Name like '%" & search.Text & "%'". But i want name, lastname inside it too. I have tried diffrent options to make this happend, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

I realise you've said Tables above, however, I suspect from your comments that you mean Columns not Tables, as you talking about querying the Last Name as well as the name?

```vb
Dim Columns As New List(Of String)

'Add as many columns as you like here...
Columns.Add("FirstName")
Columns.Add("LastName")
Columns.Add("Address")

'Initialise you Query String...
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.MyTable WHERE "

'Loop through all the columns you want to search...
For Each Column As String In Columns

    'Check if this is the last item... If so, we don't need the trailing OR!
    If ReferenceEquals(Columns.Item(Columns.Count - 1), Column) Then

        SQL &= Column & " LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%'"

    Else

        SQL &= Column & " LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%' OR "

    End If

Next

'
'Go on and perform your query...
'
```

However, if you really are referring to different tables, then you're going to have to do some joining too..

Also, as mentioned in the comments, this is unsafe, and vulnerable to SQL injection... But it will work if you're in a high trust environment...

Comment: Glad I could help! Was I right... Did you mean Columns not Tables? Feel free to accept and up-vote if the answer is correct! ;-)

Comment: You were correct. In this case, it wont work normally like "name, lastname, address" when it comes to manage serval database tables in one line. But it works perfectly when there is only one table in the line. It has to be peformed trough Columns. VB.net and Mysql are quite diffrent when it comes to database managment. But people use in most cases MS access database wich is damn easy to manage and setup things than MySql+Vb.net. Thank you so much for your help. Wish i could vote now, but i have to wait to get full reputation. Have a nice day m8 :)

Comment: No Probs... Glad I got you moving!! You can still accept the answer mind you, no reputation needed for that ;-)